# How to persist a JPA entity which has two level of oneToMany relationship?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I am having problem with persisting entities in Spring JPA/hibernate environment. I am using Lombok Plugin too to reduce boilerplate codes.
Basically I have an entity called Product which has oneToMany relationship with SubProduct :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="product")
    @EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"productId"}, callSuper=false)
    @ToString(includeFieldNames=true, callSuper=true)
    @Data
    public class Product implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="product_id")
        private Integer productId;


       @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="product"
           , cascade ={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
       private Set<SubProduct> subProducts;
   }
```

and this is my SubProduct which has another oneToMany relationship with joinTable called ProductVariantMap:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="sub_product")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"subId","product"})
@ToString(includeFieldNames=true, exclude = {"product"})
@Data
public class SubProduct implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="sub_id")
  private Integer subId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "product_id" )
  private Product product;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, 
         mappedBy="productVariantMapId.subProduct"
         , cascade =   {CascadeType.ALL})
  private List<ProductVariantMap> productVariantMaps;

}
```

This is my ProductVariantMap with an embedded id that contains productId, subId, and variantId

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product_variant_map")
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString(includeFieldNames=true)
@Data
public class ProductVariantMap implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private ProductVariantMapId productVariantMapId;

  @Column(name="variant_value", nullable=false)
  private String variantValue;
}
```

productVariantMapId:

```
@Embeddable
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"subProduct","product"})
@ToString(includeFieldNames=true,exclude = {"subProduct","product"})
@Data
public class ProductVariantMapId implements Serializable {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "sub_id" )
  private SubProduct subProduct;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "product_id" )
  private Product product;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "variant_id" )
  private Variant variant;


}
```

and last but not least is my variant:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="variant")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"variantId"})
@ToString(includeFieldNames=true)
@Data
public class Variant implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="variant_id")
    private Integer variantId;

    @Column(name="name", nullable=false)
    private String name;
}
```

My aim is to be able to persist the whole relationship in one go when I do productRepository.saveAndFlush(product). Please note that all primary keys are generated by database sequence generator and therefore its null before the saveAndFlush. I got below exception when I attempted to do the above:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.AbstractTypeDescriptor.extractHashCode(AbstractTypeDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.getHashCode(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.getHashCode(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getHashCode(EntityType.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityKey.generateHashCode(EntityKey.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityKey.<init>(EntityKey.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.generateEntityKey(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:788)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:391)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:316)
```

I traced the execution and It seemed that the exception was caused by Variant class having null HashCode which should not have been the case since I populated variant with different name for hibernate to distinguish (although the Id is not known yet) for each SubProduct (I was trying to save 2 subProducts under one product). Each subProduct will then have two productVariantMap.

I would expect to be left with 1 product row, 2 subproducts, 4 product variant map rows , and 2 variant rows.
 Is it possible to persist the whole relationship in one go in JPA? 
Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

In JPA hash and equal method have to be based on primary key. Rather not use framework to generate hash() equals() and implement it.

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
if (this == o) return true;
if (o == null || !(o instanceof Person))
    return false;

Person other = (Person)o;

if (id == other.getId()) return true;
if (id == null) return false;

// equivalence by id
return id.equals(other.getId());
}

public int hashCode() {
    if (id != null) {
        return id.hashCode();
    } else {
        return super.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Other remark:
@Embedable class is a part of entity in the same DB table. No association between embedable and its parent needed. Remove @ManyToOne

Comment: The reason why my hash and equal method is based on other fields beside ID is because I am relying on the database ID generator. If I use ID as my unique identifier , Java will treat new entities in a set as one entity since they all have null ID, see this http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html

Comment: See this line in equals method: if (id == null) return false; New objects without Id will be never same.

Comment: If I remove the manyToOne at Embeddable class, how can hibernate know which sub_id or product_id one particular productVariantMap has?. Remember that all  entities Id are null before the saveAndFlush

Comment: This is what hibernate docs says: 
 "Never use the database identifier to implement equality; use a business key, a combination of unique, usually immutable, attributes. The database identifier will change if a transient object is made persistent. If the transient instance (usually together with detached instances) is held in a Set, changing the hashcode breaks the contract of the Set. Attributes for business keys don't have to be as stable as database primary keys, you only have to guarantee stability as long as the objects are in the same Set."

Comment: Yes. If Id is null then unique identifier is super.hashCode(). Two objects without Id have different hashCodes, no problem putting them into Set then.